# Systematic ways to study the piano?

Tags: piano, practice

Let me explain:

When I began to learn the piano (the classical piano), it was in a "rough" way: I wasn't aware of interpretation, technique, etc. I thought I just needed to play the correct notes.
A little time after, I studied in a music school and I improve some skills (I studied some Chopin's waltzes and nocturnes and Beethoven's sonatas, for instance), but recently I had to travel for six months and I couldn't practice.

So, now I want to study in a systematic way, and I ask for your help!
I want to practice:

- Technique;
- Memorization (for a month/test and for a lifetime);
- Sight-reading;
- Knowledge of a reasonable number of composers and periods of music.

If you know a organized way to study (a daily schedule linked to a repertoire), I will be very grateful for your help!

Ah, and if you know a good way to study a specific music - separated hands, then together, when pay attention to the rhythm etc - I will be very pleased too!

Comment: Although it turns out that "repertory" can be used as a synonym for "repertoire", I edited it to "repertoire" to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: The Suzuki method is pretty good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gee... there isn't enough space to answer your question here or in any written, set material really. If you want to study systematically, I strongly recommend you hire a few teachers, explain what you are after, see which ones you like best, and stick with that one for a year rain or shine before reassessing where you want to go.

The problem with recommending any method is that it may be suited for some and not others.  The method will have to adapt to your style, skills, and desire.  Someone already mentioned Suzuki, which in my opinion won't do you much good for sight reading, understanding of music theory, or working on your interpretation skills, though this is a very general statement that would surely not apply to everyone learning Suzuki by all means, just to a large number of kids whom I have seen using that technique.  And again, perhaps for you, this is the best method out there. Hard to tell.  All that to say that you won't find *one* method that meets everyone's needs and is approved by everyone.

One possible "menu" to explore with whatever teacher you find and make yours based on your skills, and most importantly, your INTEREST:

- 5 mn warm up exercises (e.g. Hanon, scales, arpegios for a start)
- 5 mn sight reading (pick some compilation books of easy classical
  tunes much lower than your current level and covering a large number
  of centuries; simplified scores are ok for this).  Move on to a new
  piece every day.  Mistakes are ok.
- work on 1-2 new pieces, slightly challenging for you always but not
  by much. Try to spread the composers over the centuries.  Bach will
  cover a LOT of what you need to master.  Some romantic composers will
  allow you to improve dexterity, give more space for interpretation, but
  be more permissive w.r.t. accuracy.  Try some XXth century composers
  following your own tastes (can be Ravel/Debussy, or just some movie
  sound tracks; or the Beatles; whatever to stretch the limits of the styles
  you play really).
- last, rehearse pieces you already know so that you practice your
  accuracy, memory, and interpretation
- you can also finish with a few minutes of Jazz/blues improvisation.  Try
  composing on your own even if you really want to explore music in all its
  forms: it will greatly improve your understanding, memorisation and
  interpretation of what you already play.